# casting Oculus quest 2 with scrcpy

Tags: oculusquest

I have a simple question.

When casting oculus quest 2 with scrcpy, the casted video shows two screens while oculus app's video shows one screen.

Why Oculus quest 2's video with scrcpy shows two screens? and how can oculus app get the screen one eye sees?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3S3y.jpg)
(scrcpy)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fAgp.png)
(oculus app)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [SCRCPY](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) and get full screen view using the following command:

```
scrcpy --crop 1730:974:1934:450 --max-fps 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the previous answers, [SCRCPY](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) can capture the video shown on the two displays in the Meta/Oculus Quest 2. As the display renders the image for the screens to pass through special VR lenses, it has this unusual shape. For Quest 2, the most proper crop for landscape oriented capturing [I could find](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/2861) is `1600:900:2017:510`. It can be cropped with this command:

```
scrcpy -b25M --crop 1600:900:2017:510
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing two screens because that is literally what the screen in the Oculus headset is showing (one image for each eye).

In order to not see this, you need to provide a `-c` [crop](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy#crop) parameter. Depending on your eye spacing that you have set it the oculus headset, you may need to tweak it some, but this should get you a good starting point:

```
scrcpy -b 25M -c 1440:1540:60:60
```

(The `-b` sets the [bitrate](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy#change-bit-rate).)